# Pixel coordinates derived from real distance measurements

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

In my program (using MATLAB), I specified(through dragging) the pedestrian lane as my Region Of Interest (ROI) with the coordinates [7, 178, 620, 190] (in *xmin, ymin, width,* and *height* respectively)  using the *getrect, roipoly* and *insertshape* function. Refer to the image below.

The video from where this snapshot is taken is in 640x480 pixels resolution (480p)
[image]

---

**Defining a real world space as my ROI by mouse dragging is barbaric.** That's why the ROI coordinates must be derived mathematically.

What I'm going at is using real-world measurements from the video capturing site and use the Pythagorean Theorem from where the camera is positioned:

[image]

How do I obtain the equivalent pixel coordinates and parameters using the real-world measurements?

Comment: how is this barbaric? you would be surprised how many professional applications don't use any fancy calibration techniques but just a few manually defined rois and eyeballed scale factors and they work perfectly fine... what is your application anyway?

Comment: It's the prototype/program implementation of our Computer Science (CS) thesis. It counts the time each object (vehicle) occupies the pedestrian lane. The panel did not accept eye estimation in the ROI establishment since our thesis as CS students must be in scientific/theoretical approach not just output-based approach (for IT studs).

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to split your question into 2 smaller questions.

> A) How do I obtain the equivalent pixel coordinates of an interesting
>   point? (pratical question)

Your program shoudl be able to retrieve/reconnaise a feature/marker that you positioned in the "real-world" interesting point. The output is a coordinate in pixel. This can be done quite easily (think about QR-codes, for example)

> B) What is the analytical relationship between 1 point in 3D space and
>   its pixel coordinate in the image? (theoretical question)

This is the projection equation based on the pinhole camera model. `X,Y,Z` 3D coordinates are related with `x,y` pixel coordinates
[image: projection equation]

Cool, but some detail have to be explained (and there will be any "automatic short formula")

1. `s` represent the scale factor. A single pixel in an image could be the projection of infinite different point, due to perspective. In your photo, a pixel containing a piece of a car (when the car is present) will be the same pixel that contain a piece of street under the car (when the car is passed). 
   So there is not an univocal relationship starting from pixels coordinates
2. The matrix on the left involves the camera parameters (focal length, etc.) which are called intrinsic parameters. They have to be known to build the relationship between 3D coordinates and pixel coordinates
3. The matrix on the right seems to be trivial, is the combination of an identity matrix which represents rotation and a column array of zeros which represents translation. Something like `T = [R|t]`.
   Which rotation, which translation? You have to consider that every set of coordinates is implicitly expressed in its own reference system. So you have to determine the relationship between the reference system of your measurement and the camera reference system: not only to retrieve *position* of the camera in your 3D space with euclidean geometry, but also *orientation* of the camera (angles).

Comment: Wow!! First of all, thank you mate for the effort of providing a very informative answer. I'll have a research on existing apps, camera capability features, etc. regarding the QR-like technology that retrieves pixel coordinates. I will analyze also the relationship established in answer B to arrive at  my "short formula" for the problem.

Comment: You are welcome. I probably simplyfied too much the whole thing, so I will suggest you to read some computer vision book/web pages that will help you with the theory. Please consider to upvote my answer to mark it as useful.

Comment: As of now, regarding answer A, what I'm thinking about is to place some black (immensely darker than the road) objects on the pedestrian lane's corners and take a picture of the scene. Then I will  input this image to a program that uses Otsu's Thresholding that is calibrated for the darkest objects in the scene. Then bwconncomp and regionprops to return the pixel coordinates of the objects. I just have to choose one pair of coordinates from each side from the results and that would serve as the vertices of my ROI. What is your opinion/are your thoughts about my plan?

Comment: About the general strategy (not the specific functions) I would say that could  work, but your program will not be able to retrieve objects, only "dark areas". You may find a dark area in another point of the image. You could resolve the problem by playing with the thresholds, but a false identification is always possible.

Comment: Yes I understand the risks that's why I'll keep on adjusting the thresholds. Setting a ROI that's a little larger than the pedestrian lane to limit the detections inside would help. The strategy: Use a ROI in helping with the detection of the "object markers" that returns the pixel coordinates (close approximation, at least not eye estimation) of the vertices of the true planned ROI which is the pedestrian lane.